# Measuring distance of 3d model?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

I want to make measuring tape look like the image below:

[image]

Here the link to product on image: [Link](https://3d.si.edu/explorer?modelid=392), they use Webgl too, but not Three.js

So, How to make measuring tape for 3d model in Three.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_cubes) as reference you should be able to figure out where in the geometry you're clicking.

Having those points then is just a matter of doing this:

```
var distance = point1.distanceTo( point2 );
```